# Accessing value in JS named collection

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#FusionTablesMouseEvent), describing the `google.maps.FusionTablesMouseEvent` "row" property:

> Property: row
>
> Type: Object
>
> Description: A collection of FusionTablesCell objects, indexed by column name, representing the contents of the table row which included the clicked feature.

The `FusionTablesCell` object has two properties, `columnName` and `value`.

In my scenario, I have this little function:

```
function test(e) {
  alert(e.row);
}
```

The parameter `e` is the `FusionTablesMouseEvent` and it does indeed have a `row` property, and when I debug I can tell it has the values I need:

[image]

But I can't access the value of `PropertyId`!

When I do this:

```
alert(e.row.PropertyId);
```

It says "undefined".

This:

```
alert(e.row['PropertyId']);
```

also says "undefined".

These:

```
alert(e.row['PropertyId'].value);
alert(e.row.PropertyId.value);
alert(e.row[0].value);
```

Causes an error.

This

```
  alert(typeof(e.row));
```

Tells me `row` is indeed an object.

How do I access a value in this mysterious "collection, indexed by column name"?

Comment: Do, you tried like `e.PropertyId ` ?

Comment: I did now, but e only has four properties, "infoWindowHtml", "latLng", "pixelOffset" and "row".

Answer (score 1):

DON'T name a property "PropertyId". Changing the columnname to "ID" in my Fusion Table was all it took. Sigh...